# SQL Select Rows Where Does not Exist

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two columns, Name and Date

```
Name       Date
John       2/21/2014
Joe        2/21/2014
Sue        2/22/2014
Joe        2/22/2014
Steve      2/23/2014
John       2/23/2014
```

I need a statement that selects every Date that does NOT have a certain person.

So, for example, I need a list of dates that don't have a matching row for John, I would get just get 2/22/2014, because only Sue and Joe have records on that date.

Comment: `..GROUP BY Date HAVING Name !='John'`

Comment: @full: if you see that other people have helped you, it's worth adding a +1 for answers that look correct, as this is the way we thank people here for their effort. GoatCO's answer has a SQL Fiddle, for example, and so is likely to work for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date
FROM Table
WHERE Date NOT IN
(
   SELECT Date FROM Table where Name = 'John'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Date
FROM MyTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable t2
    WHERE t2.Name = 'John'
    AND t2.Date = t.Date
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Date
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Date
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'John' THEN 1 END) IS NULL
```

Syntax may need to be adjusted for Access.

SQL Server demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53595/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it helps! ;)

```
SELECT Date
FROM table
WHERE 'John' NOT IN Name
```